# Is there any way to batch process a method instead of calling it many times in java

Tags: java, batch-processing

I need to call a method many times, I want to know is there any other better way than having a for loop to reach this purpose

this is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < ids.size(); i++) {
    deleteMessage(currentUser, senderPeerId, messageList.get(i).getId(), contactType, uniqIds.get(i), deleteForAll);
}
```

I want to delete message method have been called for many times without using a for loop, I mean something like batch implemention

Comment: welll .... you could write a batch? But in that batch, you would also use a loop.

Comment: actually I don't know how to write a batch :(

Comment: and why don't you want to use a loop? that's basically what they are for

Comment: check stream API's, you can do something like `IntStream.range(0, ids.size()).forEach((i)-> {methodCall(i)});`, however using loop would just fine, its just whether you want to use internal iterator and focus on the work.

Comment: @Stultuske , because I want to reduce the execution time at first, and I want to have a batch feature for deleting messages

Comment: @Kayaman agreed, I dint say it's better. gave an alternative

Comment: @lia, there are multiple questions raises here when you say you want to make execution fast, are you asking for concurrent execution of `deleteMessage()` ? Can it be executed concurrently ?

Comment: @lia are you doing anything with streams here ? I believe this is not stream processing, Checkout java threading/concurrency API's. Also have look at stream and its usecase.

Comment: @lia even if you use a batch, you'll still need to use a for loop in it

Comment: No, there is no way except using a loop (or concurrently). Consider rewriting `deleteMessage()` instead. Maybe it's running SQL so you can do  `DELETE FROM messages WHERE id IN(lots, of, ids, here)`